# generating log mel spectrogram using librosa

Tags: audio, python, spectrogram

I have come across 2 different ways of generating log-mel spectrograms for audio files using librosa and I don't know why they differ in the final output, which one is "correct" or how different is one from the other.

#1

```
path = "path/to/my/file"
scale, sr = librosa.load(path)
mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(scale, sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512, n_mels=10, fmax=8000)
log_mel_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram)
librosa.display.specshow(log_mel_spectrogram, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sr)
```

#2

```
path = "path/to/my/file"
scale, sr = librosa.load(path)
X = librosa.stft(scale)
Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz')
```

The respective images are:

[image: #1][image: #2]

** EDIT ** Now that I specify the number of mel bins to be = 64, I obtain the spectrogram as below:

[image]

If I want to process many such spectrograms, should I trim off the bold blue portion above as it is common to all? What does the bold, dark region represent? Is it advisable to use fmax parameter to trim it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mel spectrogram additionally includes a step of projecting (power of) STFT bins onto Mel-frequency bins via a Mel filterbank; I don't have access to `path` so I made demo on exponential chirp:

[image]

You can visualize the kind of projection taking place by plotting the mel basis:

[image]

Note in general the two won't look alike unless `filters.mel` are carefully selected (nor do they have to).

---

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def echirp(N, fmin=.1, fmax=None, tmin=0, tmax=1):
    """https://overlordgolddragon.github.io/test-signals/ (bottom)"""
    fmax = fmax or N // 2
    t = np.linspace(tmin, tmax, N)

    a = (fmin**tmax / fmax**tmin) ** (1/(tmax - tmin))
    b = fmax**(1/tmax) * (1/a)**(1/tmax)

    phi = 2*np.pi * (a/np.log(b)) * (b**t - b**tmin)
    return np.cos(phi)

#%%
N = 2**16
n_fft, hop_length, n_mels, sr = 2048, 512, 128, 16384
x = echirp(N)

#%%
mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
    x, sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, n_mels=n_mels)
log_mel_spectrogram = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram)
librosa.display.specshow(log_mel_spectrogram, x_axis="time", y_axis="mel", sr=sr)
plt.show()

#%%
X = librosa.stft(x, hop_length=hop_length)
mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(sr, n_fft, n_mels=n_mels)
Xmel = np.dot(mel_basis, abs(X)**2)
Xdb = librosa.power_to_db(Xmel)
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz', sr=sr)
plt.show()

#%%
mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(sr, n_fft, n_mels=10)
plt.plot(mel_basis.T, color='tab:blue')
kw = dict(weight='bold', fontsize=16, loc='left')
plt.title("n_mels=10", **kw)
plt.show()

mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(sr, n_fft, n_mels=n_mels)
plt.plot(mel_basis.T, color='tab:blue')
kw = dict(weight='bold', fontsize=16, loc='left')
plt.title("n_mels=%s" % n_mels, **kw)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you answer my edit to the question above?

Comment: @VITTHALBHANDARI Yes, trim with `fmax` - also set it for `specshow` to adjust y-axis.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If my original audio was sampled at 8k Hz, can I set fmax=4k Hz (using nyquist's theorem)? It does omit almost all of the bold blue space.

Comment: Also, will upsampling the audio to 22050Hz (say), something which librosa does by default, change my audio in a way that will affect my machine learning algorithm's output?

Comment: Yes @ fmax, but it won't change output values relative to `=None` since `sr / 2` is what it defaults to (but as kwarg to `display.etc` there's slight changes). Librosa does not upsample the input, only changes certain internal parameters _as if_ input's sampling rate was `sr` (it's still important to match `sr` to actual data so just set it correctly).

Comment: @VITTHALBHANDARI If you found the answer helpful, consider accepting.